# Reuse eventlistener for different loaders Flash - AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, loader

I want to reuse my `loadImage` function that is passed a url and a string value and it loads an image into a movie clip.

I have multiple images that I want to load into different movieClips. I thought I could just pass a variable with my `addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,` but it only works the first time I load an image below is my code and below that is my error:

AS3

```
    //CALL loadImage  FUNCTION PASS URL TO LOCAL IMAGE AND UNIQUE NUMBER FOR EVENTLISTENER


loadImage('\\assets\\' + rootPath + '\\images\\bg.jpg',"1");
loadImage('\\assets\\' + rootPath + '\\images\\english.png',"2");
loadImage('\\assets\\' + rootPath + '\\images\\spanish.png',"3");

var imageLoader:Loader;

function loadImage(url:String,inc:String):void {
    trace(inc);
imageLoader = new Loader();
imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,
    function(e:Event) : void { imageLoaded(inc) });

}

function imageLoaded(counter:String):void {
    trace(counter);
if (counter == "1"){

    trace("Background");
background.addChild(imageLoader);
}else if (counter == "2"){

    trace("english");

englishMC.addChild(imageLoader);
}else if (counter == "3"){

    trace("Spanish");

spanishMC.addChild(imageLoader);
}
}
```

error:

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter listener must be non-null.
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/addEventListener()
    at Function/<anonymous>()
    at EndCap_fla::MainTimeline/processXML()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

I know I could just have seperate functions for each image loaded but if possible I would like to be able to reuse the `loadImage` function

Answer (score 1):

You should write the event handler inline, to pass your counter:

```
function loadImage(url:String,inc:String):void {
imageLoader = new Loader();
imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,
    function(e:Event) : void { imageLoaded(inc) });
}
```

Comment: Thanks that got rid of my error. But now my last image to be loaded is the only one showing and it is being loaded into were the first one should go...weird.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are overriding the same imageLoader on each load, so basically everytime the `imageLoaded` is called, you will use the last image.

In your case, I would create a new class to handle the loading of an image into a specified container, something around these lines:

```
class ResourceLoader {
    private var target: Container;
    private var loader: Loader;

    function ResourceLoader(target:Container, image: String) {
        loader = ...
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    }

    function onComplete(e: Event):void {
        target.addChild(loader);
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
new ResourceLoader(background, '\\assets\\' + rootPath + '\\images\\bg.jpg');
```

(Haven't tested the code, might have some typos)

Answer (score 0):

*(It looks like you fixed that `Error #2007` as [CapelliC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7862043/1837285) pointed it out.)*

To reuse `loadImage()`, it has to be independent from anything outside it. Your current `loadImage()` needs `imageLoader`, which you should declare inside the function instead.

`imageLoaded()` is depending on it too, but since it goes in event listener, you should get the `imageLoader` by doing `.addChild(e.currentTarget.loader)` instead of `.addChild(imageLoader)`.

That scope confusion is what's making you loose the two other loaded images (beware the closures!), because `imageLoader` is being overrided by a new instance of itself on every function call.

Also, you can easily pass any variable with your `addEventListener()` after a small change in `imageLoaded()`. That's how you should do it all:

```
loadImage("\\assets\\" + rootPath + "\\images\\bg.jpg", "1");
loadImage("\\assets\\" + rootPath + "\\images\\english.png", "2");
loadImage("\\assets\\" + rootPath + "\\images\\spanish.png", "3");

function loadImage(url:String, inc:String):void {
  trace(inc);
  var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
  imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));
  imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded(inc));
}

function imageLoaded(counter:String):Function {
  return function(e:Event):void {
    trace(counter);
    if (counter == "1") {
      trace("Background");
      background.addChild(e.currentTarget.loader);
    } else if (counter == "2") {
      trace("english");
      englishMC.addChild(e.currentTarget.loader);
    } else if (counter == "3") {
      trace("Spanish");
      spanishMC.addChild(e.currentTarget.loader);
    }
    //e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, arguments.callee);
  }
}
```

Now you can reuse both `loadImage()` and `imageLoaded()`.